# How to design a custom callback in Keras?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, callback, tqdm

I was trying to design a custom callback in keras with the following information:

```
- Number of samples processed in the current batch
- Current epoch
- Time taken to execute the current epoch
- Any metric supplied to the model in its compilation stage
- Number of epochs remaining
```

A progress bar should be displayed for the number of epochs and current epoch. I tried to use tqdm but could not figure out how to implement it. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Keras already has a progress bar that does this, what is the point?

Comment: Was doing it to learn. Would appreciate an answer.

Comment: The code in Keras for the progress bar is here: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/callbacks/callbacks.py#L537 Use it as a start and then improve your question with an actual problem. "Any help" is not really a valid question in SO.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the permalink for keras callback for ProgBar as stated earlier by @Dr. Snoopy (broken link though):
https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/461c7b1dc1797d2b05110837f5a4cd12886cc390/keras/callbacks.py#L926

It is quite interesting, I was personally looking for this to improve features of my own callbacks:

```
def set_params(self, params):
    super().set_params(params)
    self.epochs = params['epochs']
```